# Odd glmmPQL() and glht() Tukey results in R

Tags: r

I have a fairly simple data set which I'm analyzing with glmmPQL(), then using glht() for Tukey comparisons of the groups.  Group A has data with mostly numbers and a few zero values, Group B has all zeros except for one data value, and Group C is all zeros.  (I'm doing this analysis on such a sparse data set to match the work done on a more robust data set.)

my glht()/Tukey results say that A and B are different, but not A and C.  This makes no sense to me, as C is slightly further from A than B is.

Also, if I change group C by changing one of the zeros to a number (1), then glht()/Tukey sees the statistical difference between A and C, even though I actually moved the two groups closer together.

Does anyone understand why this happens?

Comment: look up "Hauck-Donner effect"

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that may explain things.